# Azure.Function.Worker Dependency Injection in UnitTest V4 .net6 paradigm

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have been tasked with upgrading a project from V2 .netcore 31 to .net6 v4. It's a beast.
The old functions used the mvc ActionResult pattern with httpRequest. Within the old, it would return for example NotFoundResult.
[image: old mvc ActionResult model]

the new model, leveraging DI and HttpRequestData/HttpResponseData changes the format considerably.
[image: .net6 V4 azure function httpworker]

*ToCustomResponse* is thowing the issue as WriteAsJsonAsync(object T) depends on HttpResponseDataExtensions within Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http. I am getting exception thrown saying
 `at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.HttpResponseDataExtensions.GetObjectSerializer(HttpResponseData response) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Http\HttpResponseDataExtensions.cs:line 275 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.HttpResponseDataExtensions.WriteAsJsonAsync[T](HttpResponseData response, T instance, String contentType, HttpStatusCode statusCode, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Http\HttpResponseDataExtensions.cs:line 141`

```
public static class ResponseHelper
{
    public static HttpResponseData ToCustomResponse(this HttpResponseData response, string? message, 
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, object? dto = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) && dto is null && statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return response;

        response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
            response.WriteString(message);

        if (dto != null)
            response.WriteAsJsonAsync(dto); // <-- Exception here as Functions.Worker.Http is not created. 

        return response;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to work around this issue? I am not finding any sample code out there to use the new model of the program or a way to inject azure.functions.worker.http. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I know when we Dependency Inject anything, the service is basically creating the object of the classes.
- But the `ResponseHeader` is a static class so it can't be injected So just add the entire `ResponseHeader` in the namespace.

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public static class ResponseHelper
    {
        public static HttpResponseData ToCustomResponse(this HttpResponseData response, string? message,
            HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, object? dto = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) && dto is null && statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return response;

            response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                response.WriteString(message);
            if (dto != null)
                response.WriteAsJsonAsync(dto); // <-- Exception here as Functions.Worker.Http is not created. 
            return response;
        }
    }
    public class Function1
    {
        
        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return response.ToCustomResponse(null,HttpStatusCode.NotFound,null);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the status code is set to Not found by the `ToCustomResponse`  even if it is set to ok in the run method.
[image]